# How can i rewrite this SQL query to select between decimals?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

How do i Rewrite this code to only show the rows WHERE Players has BattingAverage (decimal) value BETWEEN the two textbox's inputs? Also MinBatting(textbox) should be set default to 0.000 and MaxBetting(textbox) to 1.000.

as for now i can only search for a number and all players with a BattingAverage that has something with that number in it appears.

[image]

And here is my code:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

     // sql connection string
     conn.ConnectionString = "Integrated 
     Security=true;server=LUSQL01;database=Baseball";

     // sql command
     string str = "SELECT * FROM [BASEBALL].[dbo].[Players] where 
     (BattingAverage LIKE Concat('%',@search,'%'))";

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 
     txbSearch.Text;

     conn.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
     adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

     DataTable ds = new DataTable();
     adapter.Fill(ds);

     playersDataGridView.DataSource = ds;

     conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM  BaseBall.dbo.Players WHERE BattingAverage BETWEEN(minVal,MaxVal)

Comment: Try using LINQ instead of writing SQL, you will get Syntax errors showing up, instead of relying on the SQL working at runtime.

Comment: @Joagwa , good idea, so do u have any idea how my code would look like with LINQ?

Comment: Posted as an answer so I could format the code. I don't have the full context of your data structure, and how your SQLite db is setup, but you should be able to adapt. There is no LIKE command in Linq, although this article indicates there is an SqlMethods class which does. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/bursteg/2007/10/16/linq-to-sql-like-operator/

Comment: Where fieldname 'like' '%value%' is normally used with text fields.

Comment: yeah the SQL should actually use the BETWEEN operator as it is comparing two numbers, but as below, better to use LINQ to get syntax and compilation support.

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = "SELECT * FROM [BASEBALL].[dbo].[Players] where convert(float,BattingAverage) BETWEEN @min and @max";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@min", SqlDbType.Float).Value = float.Parse(txbSearch.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@max", SqlDbType.Float).Value = float.Parse(txbSearch2.Text);
```

Comment: note: there's no error handling and this will blow up if you have non floating point data in either of your text boxes or in your data.

Answer (score -1):

Linq alternative

```
var result = from player in db.Players
       where player.BattingAverage > lowestValue && player.BattingAverage < highestValue
       select player;
```

Something like that.